# Is a comma needed in following sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Is a comma needed in following sentence?

> The scientist presented his theory, and went on to attack the opponents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the comma is unnecessary, and the sentence would probably be better without it:

> The scientist presented his theory and went on to attack the opponents.

Here's why: According to [one grammar site](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp):

> In sentences where two independent clauses are joined by connectors such as *and, or, but*, etc., put a comma at the end of the first clause.
>
> > **Incorrect**: He walked all the way home and he shut the door.
> >     **Correct**: He walked all the way home, and he shut the door.

However, that same site goes on to say:

> If the subject does not appear in front of the second verb, a comma is generally unnecessary.

Therefore, if you had used a pronoun after the conjunction, you would want to keep the comma in:

> The scientist presented his theory, and he went on to attack the opponents.

---

Another [writer](https://walton.uark.edu/business-communication-lab/Resources/downloads/compound_sentences_L.pdf) put it this way:

> Two independent clauses – two sentences – separated by a coordinating conjunction – *for, an, nor, but,
>   or, yet, so* – must also be marked by a comma before the coordinating conjunction.
>
> > **Sentence A**: *Correct comma usage*: John ran to the store, but he walked home.
>
> Notice that both clauses
>   on either side of the comma can stand alone – they make sense. They also are separated by a coordinating conjunction. They need a comma.
>
> > **Sentence B**: *Incorrect comma usage*: John ran to the store, but walked home.
>
> Are both clauses able to
>   stand alone? *John ran to the store* can stand alone. *Walked home* cannot stand alone. This sentence has two of the elements – one independent clause and the coordinating conjunction – but lacks one of the key elements. *Walked home* is not an independent clause; therefore, you will not use a comma in a sentence like this one.

A friend of mine (who majored in English) taught me this guidance about 15 years ago after I had asked him to proofread a column I wrote. At first I was skeptical about what he said, but it wasn't hard to find several online writing sites echoing that same advice. It seems to be a sound rule of thumb.

---

Here is [another example](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/modulecomma.htm):

> A compound sentence must have two independent clauses – not just two verbs, two nouns, or two groups of words that are not independent clauses. Look at this example:
>
> > Joe read the book and saw the movie.
>
> In the above example, two verb groups are being joined by *and*.  The second verb group does not have a subject; thus, it is not an independent clause. Therefore, no comma belongs before *and*.

[One more](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000069.htm):

> Use a comma to separate independent clauses in a compound sentence when they are separated by a conjunction.
>
> The comma goes after the first clause and before the coordinating conjunction that separates the clauses.
>
> Make sure they are independent clauses and not some other construction where commas are not required.
>
> > **Correct**: We washed the dog, and then we cleaned up the mess that he made.
>
> This contains two independent clauses with their own subject and verb: *We washed* and *we cleaned*. The third clause, *that he made*, is a subordinate clause, so the rule does not apply.
>
> > **Incorrect**: We washed the dog, and then cleaned up his mess.
>
> There is only one subject. This is a single clause, not two independent clauses. The subject *we* has a compound verb.
>
> > **Correct**: We washed the dog and then cleaned up his mess.

Answer (score -1):

Commas are not always needed, but when used they introduce a pause.

If you think a pause there is warranted, go ahead and put one in.

Otherwise leave it out.

(Note: The trend these days is to use commas only when they're needed for clarity.)